# Storage of different-sized edges in directed adjacency-list graph

Tags: c++, memory, graph, storage

Let's say I have the following setup:

```
class Vertex;

class Edge {
    Vertex *to;
};

class Teleport : public Edge {
    int teleportCost;
};

class Walk : public Edge {
    double distance;
};

class Vertex {
    vector<Edge> adjacencies; // can only store Edge and not Walk, Teleport etc!
};
```

The problem is of course that `Vertex` can have many different type of adjacencies, and each is of different byte size. What would be the best way, then, to store the edges? My graph will never have vertices or edges removed; once it is fully built, it remains in memory until it is all destroyed at once. Perhaps this would permit a "global" storage of bytes in a big memory pool or sufficiently large `vector`, and then each `Vertex` has a `vector<void*>` or `vector<Edge*>` or something that points into the memory buffer. However, I am unsure how to do this. Could anyone help with giving some guidance on what would probably be best to use as storage in my scenario?

All `Edge`s will be used polymorphically and so I never need to cast to `Teleport` and so on.

Answer (score 1):

When a type is meant to be-subtyped, a vector or array of objects of such type is almost always wrong. You need to store a vector or array of pointers.

Instead of:

```
vector<Edge> adjacencies;
```

Use

```
vector<std::share_ptr<Edge>> adjacencies;
```

Comment: Thanks! I won't need the features of `shared_ptr` thankfully so I can use `Edge*`. I'm wondering though, wouldn't this require multiple calls to `new` internally, causing memory fragmentation? I have very strict memory requirements as the graph is huge.

Comment: @bombax: Perfect use case for a pool allocator.

Comment: @bombax, the answer is yes. The suggestion by LightnessRacesInOrbit is one way to address the problem.

Comment: Thanks! I already have a memory pool implementation. I guess my question is more how to setup the pointers into the pool properly. (My implementation has the interface `MemoryPool<T>` and `MemoryPool<T>::allocate(T &&object)`.

Comment: @bombax: There are plenty of questions on SO and resources around the internet on how to write and use custom allocators.